# How to replace multiple blank spaces with tab on a mac

Tags: macos, command-line, sed

I am trying to replace blank spaces with one tab in a fasta file, and then replace those tabs with new lines. It turns out that \t and \n do not work on mac terminal.

I have found that the \t is control+v tab, which is a major pain to type in the terminal and not conducive to copy/pasting scripts.

I have not been able to find a mac command equivalent to \n for a newline.

Desired outcome for replacing multiple blank spaces with tabs:

```
string1  string2
string1 <tab> string2
```

I have used

```
sed 's/  /control+v <tab>/g <filename
```

This works but is a pain because I need to know the exact number of consecutive blank spaces and I need to do the control+v tab deal.

For replacing each tab with a new line to get:

```
string1
string2
```

I have tried a similar method using control+v return, but that does not give the desired outcome.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match multiple spaces :

```
echo "string string" | sed -e 's/  */$'\t'/g'
```

NB : Double the space to match one or more spaces.

To add newlines on OS X :

```
echo "string string" | sed -e 's/  */\'$'\n/g'
```

The `$'\t'` and `$'\n'` are respectively for a literal tab character and new line.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for paying attention to the need for OSX workarounds! I modified my code a bit though because I couldn't get the sed with new line to work and because I am a little unfamiliar with echo.

Comment: @amwalker You're welcome but i think you'd better add a comment to detail your modifications. You can also give an answer at your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
cat File
string              string
```

To replace consecutive space with single tab:

```
sed -r 's/ +/\t/g' File
string  string
```

To replace tab with newline, use `sed 's/\t/\n/g'`:

```
sed -r 's/ +/\t/g' File | sed 's/\t/\n/g'
string
string
```

Comment: sed: illegal option -- r
    usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: Got same error (sed: illegal option -- r usage) because on OSX it should be -e not -r

Answer (score 1):

Why replace multiple spaces with tabs and then replace tabs with newlines? Why not just replace multiple spaces with newlines? Or have I missed something?

Anyway, may I recommend `tr` to you? It transliterates, squeezes, or deletes characters. So, first usage is transliterate - change 'p' to 'd' and 't' to 'g'

```
echo pot | tr 'pt' 'dg'
dog
```

Second usage is `squeeze` repeated characters, via `-s` option:

```
echo moooooo | tr -s 'o'
mo
```

Final usage is `delete` characters, via `-d`:

```
echo "minced" | tr -d "nd"
mice
```

So, coming to your question, you want to squeeze spaces and replace with linefeeds

```
tr -s ' ' < fastfile | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Comment: Hello, The reason I am doing this is in a round about way is based on the exercise for which I need the scripts, which are designed to help critical thinking and developing data analysis protocols. In short I need to know how to do both. Thanks for a transliterate refresher, however this specific answer is not useful, since as I stated above, neither \t or \n commands work in OSX. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: They both work fine on OSX - that is where I tested them.